What is an efficient way to sample a free fermion pure state from a thermal distribution?
Suppose we have a set of single particle eigenstates of fermions, $\left|\phi_i\right>$ with single particle energies $e_i$, and fixed particle number N. I would like to sample many-body (i.e. N particle) pure states according to the thermal density matrix $\rho = e^{-\beta H}/Z$. What is a computationally efficient method of doing so? I have been using a somewhat ad hoc method, which is to define a set of probabilities for each single particle eigenstate, $p_i = f(e_i)$ where $f(e_i) = \frac{1}{e^{\beta (e_i - \mu)} + 1}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution function and $\mu$ is the chemical potential corresponding to particle number N. Then, the single particle states are sampled according to the procedure
for i in (1, N) {
set $p_i := \frac{p_i}{\sum_i p_i}$
sample a single particle eigenstate $\left|\phi_k\right>$ from the probability distribution $\{p_i\}$
set $p_k := 0$ }
This procedure ensures that no single particle energy level is double occupied, and inherits it's probabilities from the Fermi-Dirac distribution, but I am not sure that this is equivalent to fully calculating the Boltzmann weight $e^{-\beta E}$ for each many body eigenstate and sampling according to that distribution (a calculation which is exponentially hard in N), even in the thermodynamic limit. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I don't understand your procedure, could you clarify? In particular, what do you mean by $p_i := \frac{p_i}{\sum_i p_i}$?

@LucasBaldo What I mean is that you normalize the probability distribution at every step, and then sample another single particle state from it. After sampling a single particle state that probability is set to zero to avoid double occupancy, after which the distribution must be normalized again.
